# Anchor tag not working in Mobile Browser

Tags: jquery, html, css

i have a slider in my website 
the anchor tag inside this slider work in PC but not working in mobile browser(android or iphone)

for example you can try "Buy Now" in first slider
[website](http://sheenashaircare.com/)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Not sure what the actual bug is, but judging from these factors:

1. I tried device mode in Chrome and it worked, but it's not working on
   my actual iPhone 6 Plus.
2. There doesn't appear to be a JavaScript
   warning related to this issue.
3. The markup is there for the link (if you hold the button down while the slider is open on an iPhone, it brings up the iOS menu at the bottom showing the URL asking if you want to open it in a new tab).

It appears there's something blocking the event on touch. This is a VERY messy method of fixing it, but it should do the trick:

```
<script type="text/javascript">

jQuery(document).ready(function($) {
  $("#buynwa").on("touchstart", function(event) {
      window.location.href = $(event.target).attr('href');
    });
 });

</script>
```

Try pasting this immediately before the `</body>` tag in your footer.php file, under any other scripts. What it will do is look for the **touchstart** event on that very first anchor tag in the first slide, grab the `href` attribute, then route to that page. If it works, the `$("#buynwa")` portion of the code will need to be adapted with the other `id`s of the other anchor tags, because there doesn't appear to be any common class shared between them. You'd inspect element, and change the jQuery selector to `$("#buynwa, #id2, #id3")`.

Comment: Thanks i used this method :D