# WordPress links not clickable on mobile

Tags: wordpress, web

My added hyperlinks are not clickable on mobile, noting that it works fine on desktop and also other built in links works fine too.
My website is built on wordpress framework and I am using Femto theme.
Please help me.

Comment: This is as vague as saying "My car won't work when it's windy. Help me."

Comment: See [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I added this piece of code in 'footer.php' before  directly and it worked like magic:

jQuery(document).ready(function($) {
      $("#buynwa").on("touchstart", function(event) {
          window.location.href = $(event.target).attr('href');
        });
     });

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32671708/anchor-tag-not-working-in-mobile-browser